# instead of "var p = new Product(myObject);" do "var p = new Product();" and then somehow populate it with myObject by using public methods? mongoose

Tags: model, mongoose

I know is possible to do:

```
var p = new Product(myObject);
```

And the `p` has the properties of `myObject`, but if I've already done:

```
var p = new Product();
```

How I might put all the data from `myObject` into `p`?

I've tried, but I know it's bad as is a protected/private method, but didn't worked too:

```
p._doc = p._buildDoc(myObject);
```

I've done and it works, **but is still using protected/private property**:

```
p._doc = modelInstance._doc;
```

Why?
I need to make a copy from a document to another, but both are on a different connection. I can't use the first approach because of the way it works, it would be a lot less flexible.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`extend`](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#extend) method of the underscore library (or the same technique that method uses internally) to apply the properties of `myObject` to `p`:

```
_.extend(p, myObject);
```